# create_function() to function() Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in

Tags: php, function, parse-error, create-function

I am converting a creat_function to function for PHP 8.0. I just need a fresh pair of eyes on this. I can not see where the '}' issue is. Does anyone see it? Otherwise the code should work correct?

```
function roots_root_relative_url($input) {
    $output = preg_replace_callback(
        '!(https?://[^/|"]+)([^"]+)?!',
        function($matches){
            // if full URL is site_url, return a slash for relative root
            'if (isset($matches[0]) && $matches[0] === site_url()) { return "/";' .
            // if domain is equal to site_url, then make URL relative
            '} elseif (isset($matches[0]) && strpos($matches[0], site_url()) !== false) { return $matches[2];' .
            // if domain is not equal to site_url, do not make external link relative
            '} else { return $matches[0]; };'
        
        } **< OFFENDING BRACKET**
        
        $input
    );
    return $output;
}
```

I removed the '}' but then I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$input' (T_VARIABLE) in directory on line 56" What in the world am I missing???

Comment: A comma. You're missing a `,` immediately after the `}`, to separate the parameters in `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: Why is that function body a string?

Comment: No idea. This is a very old theme I am trying to get errors out of.  Any suggestions for how it should be? I would be grateful. This is a pain!

Comment: Tried the , and get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in directory on line 46" Line 46 is },

Comment: Remove the `'`s and `' .`s so it becomes code that can be executed: https://3v4l.org/9qoFF

Comment: omg...I feel like an idiot on that one. Thank you! Those are removed and now it is executable but now getting a Parse error on the , after the }

Comment: Cannot reproduce, see the 3v4l link I posted - works without Parse error

Comment: Strange, I copied the code from your link and pasted it. Worked. Something must have been missing on my side. Thank you!